Specialize function template for all types of pointers
I want to implement a streaming style logging lib.
I made a Log_t class to buffer a log entry, and do real output up on it being
destroyed, like this:
class Log_t: public std::ostringstream {
    static int log_id;
public:
    Log_t() { ++log_id; };
    ~Log_t() override {
        // in order to simplify discussion, here output it to cout
        std::cout << "log" << log_id << ':' << str() << std::endl;
    };
};

int Log_t::log_id {};

template <typename T>
Log_t& operator<<( Log_t& log_, const T& body_ ) {
    static_cast<std::ostream&>( log_ ) << body_;
    return log_;
};

Whenever I have a customized class/struct, I can log it in same way, as long as
I implemented a output function for it. Like this:
struct Response_t {
    int _id;
};

// Using std::ostream instead of Log_t, as it may be outputed to other targets
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os_, const Response_t& rsp_ ) {
    return os_ << "resp_id:" << rsp_._id;
};

Then I can log it as:
Response_t response {123};
Log_t() << "local obj=" << response;

But in fact Response_t mainly is returned by a lib, and in pointer form instead
of a real ojb/ref, so I should probably output the contents that be pointed by
instead of a address, and I have to check if it is a nullptr, before logging it.
Furthermore, I don't wana check if it is a nullptr in every customized output
functions, instead I want to check it only once in the logging function template.
I changed the function template into these two:
template <typename T>
Log_t& operator<<( Log_t& log_, const T* body_ ) {
    if( body_ == nullptr )
        static_cast<std::ostream&>( log_ ) << "{nullptr}";
    else
        static_cast<std::ostream&>( log_ ) << *body_;
    return log_;
};

template <typename T>
Log_t& operator<<( Log_t& log_, const T& body_ ) {
    static_assert( ! std::is_null_pointer_v<T> );
    static_assert( ! std::is_pointer_v<T> );

    static_cast<std::ostream&>( log_ ) << body_;
    return log_;
};

The complete codes:
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>

class Log_t: public std::ostringstream {
    static int log_id;
public:
    Log_t() { ++log_id; };
    ~Log_t() override { std::cout << "log" << log_id << ':' << str() << std::endl; };
};

int Log_t::log_id {};

/*
    Let's say that parameter body_ is a pointer received from another lib,
    so it may be a nullptr, and I don't wana check if it is a nullptr
    everywhere in my projects, instead I want to check it only once in the
    following function.
*/
template <typename T>
Log_t& operator<<( Log_t& log_, const T* body_ ) {
    if( body_ == nullptr )
        static_cast<std::ostream&>( log_ ) << "{nullptr}";
    else
        static_cast<std::ostream&>( log_ ) << *body_;
    return log_;
};

template <typename T>
Log_t& operator<<( Log_t& log_, const T& body_ ) {
    static_assert( ! std::is_null_pointer_v<T> );
    static_assert( ! std::is_pointer_v<T> );

    static_cast<std::ostream&>( log_ ) << body_;
    return log_;
};

struct Response_t {
    int _id;
};
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os_, const Response_t& rsp_ ) {
    return os_ << "resp_id:" << rsp_._id;
};

int main() {
    Response_t response {123};
    Log_t() << "local obj=" << response;

    // Suppose rsp_ptr is received from elsewhere, may be nullptr!
    Response_t* rsp_ptr = &response;
    Log_t() << "ptr obj=" << rsp_ptr;
    rsp_ptr = nullptr;
    Log_t() << "ptr obj=" << response;

    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
};

But I can NOT pass through the compilation, and got this:

ostream-ptr.cpp:36:31: error: static assertion failed    36 |
static_assert( ! std::is_pointer_v );

It looks like the specialized version for pointers has been ignored by gcc-12.3?
Maybe I can resolve it with concept of c++20?
How to code it?

Following is also possible: const T*&. Use SFINAE with std::is_pointer_v<std::remove_cvref_t<t>>

The const T* overload isn't getting ignored. The const T& overload is just more specialized.
Consider this example:
template <typename T>
void f(const T*) {}

template <typename T>
void f(const T&) {}

int main() {
    int i;
    f(i); // calls the ref overload as expected, with T = int
    int* p = &i;
    f(p); // still calls the ref overload, but with T = int*
    const int* pc = &i;
    f(pc); // correctly calls the pointer overload, with T = int
}

Demo
If you add a third overload void f(T*) without the const, then the second call (f(p)) uses that one.
I assume you want the const T* overload to be called whenever a pointer is passed, const or not. In this case, in C++20, you can add a requires clause to disable the const T& overload:
template <typename T>
requires(!std::is_pointer_v<T>)
Log_t& operator<<( Log_t& log_, const T& body_ ) { ... }

Demo
Before C++20, you can similarly use SFINAE.
Also, note that the line rsp_ptr = nullptr; does not make rsp_ptr a nullptr in the sense that the type of rsp_ptr does not change to std::nullptr_t, which is what std::is_null_pointer checks. It only sets rsp_ptr to an integral value of zero.
To test your log for actual std::nullptr_t values, you need to pass nullptr explicitly (or make a std::nullptr_t variable):
Log_t() << "ptr obj=" << nullptr;

This will fail, and so you may want to update the requires clause to:
requires(!std::is_pointer_v<T> and !std::is_null_pointer_v<T>)

You can also remove the static_asserts, since they just repeat the requires clause.

Good answer.  f(p); // still calls the ref overload, but with T = int* - don't you just love C++ (!)

@Nelfeal Thanks a lot!  But we forgot a thing. How about "const char*"? Eventhough it is a pointer, but we need to call the ref version of the func with it. Should we?

@Leon Whether you should is entirely your choice. If you mean that you always want to treat a const char* as a null-terminated string and pass it directly to the stream, then I'd just add an additional overload (not templated and so prioritized).
